# "grouping variable must not contain purely numeric items"

Tags: r

I am doing an analysis with groups and as such, need to make a grouping variable, for which I wanted to use gender (0=male, 1=female). What I first did was create a vector of this variable (manual told me to do this), but then I got an eror that: "grouping variable must not contain purely numeric items". Then I transformed my vector in a logical (TRUE/FALSE), but somehow I still get this error.

So my question is, does anyone know, in general terms, what may be the problem when I get this error?

Attached below is the code to the head of my dataset:

```
structure(c(7, 8, 7, 5, 6, 6, 4.9, NA, 6.9, 5.1, 5.8, NA, NA, 
        NA, 7, 3, 7, NA, NA, NA, 6.7, 4.1, 5.9, NA, NA, NA, 5, 6, 7, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA, 6.2, 
        4.3, 6.3, NA, NA, NA, 7, 5, 7, NA, NA, NA, 6.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, 6, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, 16, 0.001, 12, 11, 11, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 12, 12, 12, 
        0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 12, 12, 12, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 15, 12, 
        12, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 16, 0.001, 12, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 
        0.001, 0.001, 15, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 16, 0.001, 
        0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 24L), .Dimnames = list(c("800009", 
                                                                 "800012", "800015", "800033", "800042", "800045"), c("gener_sat_T0", 
                                                                                                                      "sel_T0", "gener_sat_T1", "sel_T1", "gener_sat_T2", "sel_T2", 
                                                                                                                      "gener_sat_T3", "sel_T3", "gener_sat_T4", "sel_T4", "gener_sat_T5", 
                                                                                                                      "sel_T5", "gener_sat_T6", "sel_T6", "gener_sat_T7", "sel_T7", 
                                                                                                                      "dT1", "dT2", "dT3", "dT4", "dT5", "dT6", "dT7", "female")))
```

Then what I am trying to do is fit a CT model (have used it before on non-group data and that worked fine).

```
CTMODEL <- ctModel(n.latent = 2, n.manifest = 2, Tpoints = 8, 
                   manifestNames = c("gener_sat", "sel"), 
                   latentNames = c("gener_sat", "sel"), LAMBDA = diag(2))
fit_CTMODEL <- ctMultigroupFit(datawide = data_wide, groupings=female, ctmodelobj = CTMODEL)
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You are right; I am using the ctsem package. I have read the ?ctMultigroupFit but  find it's not really helpful at all. All it says is: "Vector of character labels designating group membership for each row of datawide. These will be prefixed on relevant parameter estimates in the summary."

Comment: I guess you need to use `data_wide$female` instead of `female`?

Comment: This gives me the following error. I think it has to do with the fact that I had long data (=dataset), which I used the ctLongtoWide and then ctIntervalise code on. However, the resulting intervalised "dataset" is a matrix.

Error in withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w) invokeRestart("muffleWarning")) : 
  object 'data_wide' not found

Comment: hmm i'm not sure what to tell you since i don't know the `ctsem` package. i recommend running `debugonce(ctMultigroupFit)` and going through the function step by step to see what's gone awry.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I redid your computations, albeit your code was not reproducible directly, I made some changes and now it works:

```
# create the structure object (data_wide), and change it to remove the 
# grouping:

data_wide = structure(c(7, 8, 7, 5, 6, 6, 4.9, NA, 6.9, 5.1, 5.8, NA, NA, 
    NA, 7, 3, 7, NA, NA, NA, 6.7, 4.1, 5.9, NA, NA, NA, 5, 6, 7, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA, 6.2, 
    4.3, 6.3, NA, NA, NA, 7, 5, 7, NA, NA, NA, 6.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 6, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 16, 0.001, 12, 11, 11, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 12, 12, 12, 
    0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 12, 12, 12, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 15, 12, 
    12, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 16, 0.001, 12, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 
    0.001, 0.001, 15, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 16, 0.001), .Dim = 
c(6L, 23L), 
    .Dimnames = list(c("800009", "800012", "800015", "800033", "800042", 
"800045"), 
                     c("gener_sat_T0",  "sel_T0", "gener_sat_T1", "sel_T1", 
"gener_sat_T2", 
                       "sel_T2", "gener_sat_T3", "sel_T3", "gener_sat_T4", 
"sel_T4", "gener_sat_T5", 
                       "sel_T5", "gener_sat_T6", "sel_T6", "gener_sat_T7", 
 "sel_T7", 
                       "dT1", "dT2", "dT3", "dT4", "dT5", "dT6", "dT7")))


CTMODEL <- ctModel(n.latent = 2, n.manifest = 2, Tpoints = 8, 
               manifestNames = c("gener_sat", "sel"), 
               latentNames = c("gener_sat", "sel"), LAMBDA = diag(2))
fem = c("f", "m", "f", "f", "m", "f") # grouping, which needs to be a 
# character vector

fit_CTMODEL <- ctMultigroupFit(dat = data_wide, groupings=fem, ctmodelobj = 
CTMODEL) # dat instead of datawide
```

So in the end it's just a matter of making the grouping variable character vector.

Add: the code runs but hives various errors:

```
Not all eigenvalues of Hessian are greater than 0
Fit attempt generated errors
Retry limit reached
```

I guess that's because of the model and leave the solution to you :)

Comment: Ok, then, as @MichaelChirico said, we might need a reproducible example

Comment: It's attached to the main post!

Comment: This is great, Eudald, thank you so much! I've got the code up and running! (: